# Get the function for a specific line in a C source file

Tags: c, code-analysis

Is there some tool which I could use to find out the function name to which a specified source line number belongs?

Example file:

```
static enum foo bar(int c)
{
    if (c < 30)
        return B1;
    else
        return B2;
}

static enum foo somethingelse(void)
{
    return B3;
}
```

For line 4 `return B1;` the answer should be `bar`.

I use [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) source syntax. The source code can only be compiled with GCC due to its dependencies.

C99 is a specification for C. Ansi C would be C89. But there are for example things like K&R C - rather important when it is about parsing the source file to find the function names.

The question was closed as off topic on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600645/get-the-function-for-a-specific-line-in-a-c99-source-file).

Comment: Is a command-line tool OK? For what operating system?

Comment: Do you want the tool to support things that most people don't use, such as K&R C, or is it enough if it works with code that respects modern, decent coding conventions? Does it have to understand preprocessor definitions (e.g. if the function definition line is in #ifdef blocks), or is a simple textual analysis ok? Does it have to understand unusual presentations like a function definition that's intended?

Comment: Hmph, just now noticed this is closed.  OP's question seems perfectly clear to me (see my "perfectly clear" answer).   It fails SR requirements of being clear what platform constraints for the tool, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html?Home=CTools) could be easily used to do this.

DMS parses and builds ASTs for a langauge defined to it.  The C Front end defines a variety of C dialects to DMS, including C99.  The result of applying the C Front end with DMS to a C file (complete with preprocessor directives/expansion, etc.) is an AST with every node stamped as to its grammar rule type, with source file, line, and column.

Given such a tree, one can use DMS's ASTInterface to start at the root, walk over the tree until a node with line number 4 is found.  Under the presumption that is inside a function (it may not be), you can easily walk up the tree to a node which is a function declaration, and then down one node to the function id, and then print the string associated with that node.

The code to accomplish with DMS looks like:

```
(define FindFunctionName
   (lambda (function natural [FileName (reference string)] [target_line_number natural])
   (local (;; (= [my_tree AST:Node] (C~GCC4:ParserComponent:Parse FileName)
               (= [current_node AST:Node] (AST:FindInSubtree my_tree
                      (lambda (function boolean AST:Node)
                           (== (AST:GetLineNumber ?) target_line_number)
                      )lambda )=
            );;
       (= current_node (AST:FindParent current_node
                          (lambda (function boolean AST:Node)
                              (== (AST:GetNodeType ?)
                                  C~GCC4:ParserComponent:TokenNumber:function_declaration)
                          )lambda )=
       (return (AST:GetStringLiteral (AST:GetNthChild current_node 2)) ; id node under function_declaration
    )local
```

DMS uses a lisp-syntax style parallel programming language named PARLANSE for its metaprogramming language.  I think what the above does is pretty clear. I've left out all the error checking (although PARLANSE exceptions will do most of it for the programmer) for expository reasons.

DMS is unique in the sense that you don't necessarily have to expand all the preprocessor directives to parse the text.  The C Front end has one mode in which "well-structured" PP directives are simply parsed and retained in the tree; it can't handle PP conditional that span C nonterminals.  You can still find the function name the same way, but you might have to worry that the identifier found in the function declaration is actually a macro, or might be wrapped in a conditional.  The C front has another experimental mode (we think it works but are still checking) in which PP directives can be parsed in spite of arbitrary placement.  You still have to worry about PP directives affecting the function name.  But these two modes let one manipulate many C programs without having to configure the preprocessor correctly or even at all.

I'm sure you can configure Clang to do this line number extraction; AFAIK, it can only do this by do full preprocessing.  Clang is designed to be used for tasks like this, but mostly only for C and C++.

You can probably do this with GCC, but GCC wasn't designed to be helpful, so the effort to do this is probably a lot more than you'd expect.

The EDG front end can parse C, and I'm sure you do something similar with it after expanding the preprocessor declarations.

I don't have a lot of experience with the latter 3 although I've been tracking their evolution for literally decades.

Comment: Sorry, but I gave up on stackexchange. The mods here crippled my question to a point where it doesn't make sense anymore and then blocked the question because it isn't clear what I asked.

Comment: But thanks for your very detailed reply

Comment: @ConchúrNavid:  SO is outright unreasonable on this kind of question.  SR is intended to encourage it, but they are cranky about getting enough detailed requirements so the answers can be clearly judged.  I think if you adjust the text slightly, you get the "on hold" removed.